# PLS-00302: Le composant 'GEN_BULL_PAY' must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I have this procedure but When I try to execute it it returns me this message:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMAUSER.GEN_BULL_PAY(p_deadline IN VARCHAR2)
as
BEGIN
    select BULL_ROW
    from SCHEMAUSER.BULL_CP
    where adress is not null and ACCOUNT_TYPE = 'NATIO'
        and TERM = to_date(p_deadline , 'dd/mm/yyyy')
       or (ACCOUNT_TYPE is null or CODE_PAYMENT_METHOD = 'M')
    order by NUM_RCAR, ITEM_ORDER;
    commit;
end;
```

After executing this query:

```
begin
    SCHEMAUSER.GEN_BULL_PAY;
end;
```

I get this:

```
[2023-07-13 15:45:06] [65000][6550]
[2023-07-13 15:45:06]   ORA-06550: Ligne 2, colonne 17 :
[2023-07-13 15:45:06]   PLS-00302: PLS-00302: component 'GEN_BULL_PAY' must be declared
[2023-07-13 15:45:06]   ORA-06550: Ligne 2, colonne 5 :
[2023-07-13 15:45:06]   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
[2023-07-13 15:45:06] Position: 22
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, procedure is **invalid**; PL/SQL requires an `INTO` clause, and you don't have it.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure scott.gen_bull_pay
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    select loc
  5    from dept
  6    where deptno = 10;
  7  end;
  8  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE SCOTT.GEN_BULL_PAY:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/3      PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
SQL> begin
  2    scott.gen_bull_pay;
  3  end;
  4  /
  scott.gen_bull_pay;
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PLS-00302: component 'GEN_BULL_PAY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL>
```

---

Let's make it valid:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure scott.gen_bull_pay
  2  as
  3    l_loc dept.loc%type;
  4  begin
  5    select loc
  6    into l_loc
  7    from dept
  8    where deptno = 10;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

As of error you got: I suspect that there's another object in that schema that shares the same name as schema itself. For example, a package:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create or replace package scott as
  2    c_num number := 0;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.
```

So, when you call function by specifying owner name (`scott` in my example), Oracle complains because - in my example - `gen_bull_pay` doesn't exist in package named `scott`:

```
SQL> begin
  2    scott.gen_bull_pay;
  3  end;
  4  /
  scott.gen_bull_pay;
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PLS-00302: component 'GEN_BULL_PAY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

If you omit owner name, it works:

```
SQL> begin
  2    gen_bull_pay;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

For some more info, have a look at [Name Resolution in Schema Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_dependencies.htm#ADFNS99985)